# Using nodejs fetch loop

Tags: node.js, loops, fetch

I run this code I want to send the request immediately but after all the for loop is executed.
I want to do other things in the loop and not wait for answers. I will react to the answers whenever they come

```
var fetchUrl = require("fetch").fetchUrl;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  checkbalance(i);
}

function checkbalance(req) {
  var urlCheckBalance =
    "https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balancemulti&address=" +
    req +
    "&tag=latest&apikey=<api key>";

  // source file is iso-8859-15 but it is converted to utf-8 automatically
  fetchUrl(urlCheckBalance, function (error, meta, body) {
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
}
```

response is here: all sequence number generate after that fetch run

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
{"status":"0","message":"NOTOK","result":"Error! Invalid address format"}
{"status":"0","message":"NOTOK","result":"Error! Invalid address format"}
{"status":"0","message":"NOTOK","result":"Error! Invalid address format"}
{"status":"0","message":"NOTOK","result":"Max rate limit reached"}
{"status":"0","message":"NOTOK","result":"Max rate limit reached"}
```

Comment: You mean you need to complete all fetch requests from each loop iteration? In parallel or consecutive?

Comment: yes. I want requests execute between for loop

Comment: remove your apiKey from code snippet, you should keep it in secret

Comment: it is not very important it is public

Comment: your code is doing what you want, but the loop is running faster than the first response... try it and you will see, it will keep the loop 

for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  if(i < 10) checkbalance(i);
}

Answer (score 1):

Check out how [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) works and what [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is.

You can rewrite your code to async execution:

```js
const { fetchUrl } = require('fetch');

const checkbalance = req => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const urlCheckBalance = '...'; // URL here
    fetchUrl(urlCheckBalance, (error, meta, body) => {
        return error ? reject(error) : resolve(body);
    })
})

const executeOneByOne = async () => {
    try {
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            const resultBody = await checkbalance(i);
            console.log(i, resultBody);
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('Error :(');
    }
}

executeOneByOne();
```

Now all requests executing one by one:

```
0 {"status":"0","message":"NOTOK","result":"Error! Invalid address format"}
1 {"status":"0","message":"NOTOK","result":"Error! Invalid address format"}
2 {"status":"0","message":"NOTOK","result":"Error! Invalid address format"}
...
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want the loop to continue and show the answer when it returns. for example :0 
1
2 {"status":"0","message":"NOTOK","result":"Error! Invalid address format"}
3 
4{"status":"0","message":"NOTOK","result":"Error! Invalid address format"}

Comment: Async execution return data immediately after request finished, so this code already logging data instantly.

Comment: Is it good. But "for" has to wait for an answer. I want to do other things in the loop and not wait for answers. I will react to the answers whenever they come

Comment: Ok, then I don't realize what do you actually want, because your code from question doing what you ask: you logged responses when they come, no matter how loop iterating.

Comment: I do not want consecutive numbers to wait for the server to respond. Your code The next number is waiting for the server to respond